# configure hibernate with embedded tomcat 7 programmatically

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, hsqldb, embedded-tomcat-7

I am trying to configure a embedded tomcat instance in my app without any configuration files.

I have done some research and based upon this [long tutorial](http://www.ehow.com/how_7999843_stepbystep-hibernate-tomcat-mysql-tutorial.html) and [a shorter one](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingHibernateWithTomcat) i extracted this steps:

1. Create a `ServletContextListener`

   ```
   @WebListener //some articles on the web mentioned, that this would add the 
   //Listener automatically to the app context, but i cant believe that this works in my case
   public class HibernateListener implements ServletContextListener {

       public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
           HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(); // create a factory
       }

       public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
           HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close(); // free resources
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add that Listener to the app context

   ```
   Context rootCtx = tomcat.addContext("", base.getAbsolutePath());
   rootCtx.getServletContext().addListener("com.example.listeners.HibernateListener");

   tomcat.start();
   tomcat.getServer().await();
   ```
3. Implement the `HibernateUtil` class with the necessary configuration

   ```
   public class HibernateUtil {

       private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

       static {
           try {
               //should i call .configure() on the returned Configuration here?                
               sessionFactory = getConfiguration()
                       .buildSessionFactory();
           } catch (Throwable ex) {
               System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
               throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
           }

       }

       private static Configuration getConfiguration(){
           Configuration c = new Configuration();

           c.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:1234/mydb1");
           c.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "SA");
           c.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "");
           c.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");


           c.setProperty("dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
           c.setProperty("cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider");
           c.setProperty("cache.use_query_cache", "false");
           c.setProperty("cache.use_minimal_puts", "false");
           c.setProperty("max_fetch_depth", "3");

           c.setProperty("show_sql", "true");
           c.setProperty("format_sql", "true");
           c.setProperty("hbm2ddl.auto", "create");

           c.addPackage("com.example.models");
           c.addAnnotatedClass(MyClass.class);

           return c;
       }

       public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
           return sessionFactory;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Now i should somehow work with `MyClass` to create and retrieve data from the linked database through hibernate, right? (right now i am not sure, how exactly, but thats not the point here)

But unfortunately i am getting a `NullPointerException` when im trying to add the listener to tomcat

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.addListener(ApplicationContext.java:1278)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.addListener(ApplicationContextFacade.java:649)

which points to the line `rootCtx.getServletContext().addListener("com.example.listeners.HibernateListener");`

**EDIT 1**

But if i am running **hibernate standalone** (without tomcat) it works **fine**. The Data is being saved without errors!

In `HibernateUtil`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass mycls = new MyClass();

    mycls.setMyProperty("My Property");
    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(mycls);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

So the way i am configuring hibernate is fine i think. The error has something to do with the listener adding...

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

After a deep digging in the source code of Tomcat I have found one possible solution:

```
rootCtx.addApplicationListener(new ApplicationListener("com.example.listeners.HibernateListener", false));
```

It does what I needed!

Comment: Have a look here. The applicationlistener of tomcate is not the right place for the initialization since a hibernate configzration belongs the the web application. http://mrbool.com/working-with-servlet-context-listeners-in-java/29304

Comment: Hm. But it looks like tomcat does just that when you configure a listener in web.xml. See the [source](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc7.0.x/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/deploy/WebXml.java) in `public void configureContext(Context context)`

Comment: @ali what is teh rootctx coming from?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missing the invocation of the method cinfigure() of the configuraton c 
right after your initialisation.

So it should look like this::

```
 SessionFactory sessionFactory =  getConfiguration().confgure().buildSessionFactory();
```

or

```
c = getConfiguration();
sessionFactory = c.configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

UPDATE

In order to add complete properties at runtim you can create a Prperties object and use the method.

```
  configuration.buildSettings(Properties props)
```

I am not sure but using this approach it could be pssible that hibernate not looks for the hibernate.cfg.xml or .properties within classpath .

UPDATE

What you can try additionally to invoke your getConfiguration method within the getSessionFactory method instead of calling it within the static initializer of the HibernateUtil  expliciteLy

```
public static getSessionFactory() {
    Configuration c = getConfiguration();
    sessionFactory = c.buildSessionFactory();
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have tested running your suggestion with hibernate standalone and got this Exception: `Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found`. I have updated my question. After some testing i can tell that the configuration of **hibernate** itself is fine.

Comment: I would suggest to put an hibernate.cfg.xml within your web-inf folder. It could be empty between the hibernate-configuration element since you set all properties within your application

Comment: Also have a look at this discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074678/setting-properties-programmatically-in-hibernate

Comment: Sorry under WEB-INF/classes

Comment: Well, as i mentioned in my updated question, hibernate works just fine executing the `main` method of `HibernateUtil` without an hibernate.cfg.xml file and without calling `configuration.configure()`. Why do you still think that the problem lies here?