# How is possible to set up hibernate programmatically

Tags: java, hibernate

Sorry, I am curious if is possible (and if it is, how is possible) to set up the database on what is hibernate working from a running web application, well something like to modify properties.xml or hiberanete.xml from a page of the site.

Thank you,
Vlad.

Comment: Sorry, your question is not well written and could have different meanings. I would suggest to first read a book or at least a tutorial. Please ask more specific questions here.

Comment: Please have a look on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074678/setting-properties-programmatically-in-hibernate),

Comment: And hibernate and jsf have no direct relation at all. Your code is the glue between them (if needed)