# How to set the hibernate.connection.password as an encrypted value in hibernate.cfg.xml and then decrypt it to be used in the config?

Tags: java, hibernate, encryption

I am trying to create a encrypted value in the properties for hibernate.connection.password.  At run time the encrypted value is picked up and decrypted.  I then try to overwrite the properties in the HibernateUtil.  But even after decryption the value doesn't seemed to be used because it fails to authenticate. How would I get this to work?

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    private static final String keyFile="/keys/.aoo1key";
    static {
        try {
                Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
                String passwordToDecrypt=cfg.getProperty("hibernate.connection.password");
                if(passwordToDecrypt.startsWith("ENC(")&&passwordToDecrypt.endsWith(")")) {
                    passwordToDecrypt = passwordToDecrypt.substring(4,passwordToDecrypt.length()-1);
                    PropertiesEncryption propertiesEncryption = new PropertiesEncryption(keyFile);
                    String decrypted = propertiesEncryption.decryptValue(passwordToDecrypt);
                    cfg.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", decrypted);
                }

                StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = cfg.getStandardServiceRegistryBuilder().build();

                Metadata metaData = new MetadataSources(standardRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
                sessionFactory = metaData.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        } catch (Throwable th) {

            System.err.println("Enitial SessionFactory creation failed" + th);

            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(th);

        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

        return sessionFactory;

    }


}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>


<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate5</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
 <!--  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">dog</property>   -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">ENC(MYFBqlDom8ZawVi+toB3PU0MdI10Desvsq4D2Z5lejk=)</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

<mapping class="net.model.Employee" />

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The Exception

```
Enitial SessionFactory creation failedorg.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.roseindia.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:66)
    at net.roseindia.GetAllData.main(GetAllData.java:18)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at net.roseindia.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:60)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:910)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3923)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1273)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2031)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: there is some support through spring. are you using spring in your project.

Comment: Right now I am trying to figure out how to do this with a sample project before I start breaking old code that works.  Do you have something that I can look at?  The real project isn't using spring mvc or boot because it's not a web app.  It is a ETL.  The datasource was so bad that I couldn't use a tool.  I am using hibernate to create tables and the relationships.

Comment: let try with this. http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-configuration.html

Comment: also with http://www.jasypt.org/hibernate.html#

Comment: I have seen this and I was able to get it to work with normal properties files.  But reading the hibernate.cfg.xml with .load will fail because load is expecting a normal properties file.  Loading with .loadFromXML will fail because of the namespace.  I haven't tried the integration because it doesn't say that it supports hibernate 5.  I am thinking of trying it anyway and see what errors I may get.

Comment: here you error saying that Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES). so you tried with password YES. is it mean your decryption works fine ?

Comment: With the code I pasted above, the decryption works fine.  But when I try to overwrite the existing password in the Configuration object, the new value isn't used for authentication.  So, I have been trying to find a work around.

Comment: try to use hibernate.properties not hbm.cfg.xml. ex : https://javapapers.com/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-and-sessionfactory-instantiation/

Comment: I found a work around and it works now, look at my post below.

Comment: whats the behavior of StandardServiceRegistryBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I broke it down into steps I can get it to do what I want. I was doing the build at the same time I was instantiating the StandardServiceRegistry.  That seems to have been the main problem with my code. Plus I found that I should set the decrypted password with standardServiceRegistryBuilder.applySetting and not with the Configuration object.

```
StandardServiceRegistry standardRegistry = cfg.getStandardServiceRegistryBuilder().build();
```

it works like this

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory =buildSessionFactory();
    private static final String keyFile="/keys/.aoo1key";

     // Hibernate 5:
    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration cfg = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            // Create the ServiceRegistry from hibernate.cfg.xml
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder standardServiceRegistryBuilder = cfg.getStandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
            //Get the encrypted value
            String passwordToDecrypt=cfg.getProperty("hibernate.connection.password");
            //Test if it is encrypted
            if(passwordToDecrypt.startsWith("ENC(")&&passwordToDecrypt.endsWith(")")) {
                //Stripping "ENC(" and ")" 
                passwordToDecrypt = passwordToDecrypt.substring(4,passwordToDecrypt.length()-1);
                //TODO Key file is the key to use for decrytion, the name of my class PropertiesEncryption is kind of bad, what should I call it?
                PropertiesEncryption propertiesEncryption = new PropertiesEncryption(keyFile);
                String decrypted = propertiesEncryption.decryptValue(passwordToDecrypt);
                //Overwrite the encrypted value
                standardServiceRegistryBuilder.applySetting("hibernate.connection.password", decrypted);
            }


            //This will build even if the password wasn't never encrypted
            serviceRegistry =standardServiceRegistryBuilder.build();
            // Create a metadata sources using the specified service registry.
            Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();

            return metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {

            if (serviceRegistry != null) {
                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(serviceRegistry);
             }

            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
       // getSessionFactory().close();
        if (serviceRegistry != null) {
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(serviceRegistry);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really change anything. Your decryption key is still available in plaintext.

Comment: Yes, the key is in text, but the real password isn't exposed in the code or on the host.  So, it was a starting point.  The key/password is probably rotated on a regular basis and stored externally with permissions so only the app can read it at startup.

Comment: How does this external service recognize the app? Does the app use a secret to authenticate with this external device? Where is this secret stored?

Comment: I made this post 4 years ago.  From what I remember... the password(secret) is stored in the local conf file already encrypted.  The dev ops team does the magic of providing a protected key.  They also do the magic of rotating key and secrets during deployments.  It is a combination of s3, permissions, and some magic that I don't manage.