# Set Hibernate mapping values using Java code

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to set Hibernate configuration using Java code:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                          "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        .........................
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <mapping class="com.web.models.RfidReaderModel"/>
        <mapping class="com.web.models.SensorModel"/>
        <mapping class="com.web.models.WhiteListModel"/>
        <mapping class="com.web.models.BlackListModel"/>
        <mapping class="com.web.models.ClientCardModel"/>
        <mapping class="com.web.models.SystemUserModel"/>
        <mapping class="com.web.models.AuditLogModel"/>

        <mapping class="com.web.models.EntranceWFModel"/>
        <mapping class="com.web.models.ExitWFModel"/>
        <mapping class="com.web.models.RolesPermissions"/>
        <mapping class="com.web.models.SystemUserRole"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I tried this code implementation:

```
public static SessionFactory buildTestSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        //configuration.configure();
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:sqlite:/opt/testDB.sqlite");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.sqlite.JDBC");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.release_mode", "auto");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.autoReconnect", "true");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        configuration.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");


    return configuration.buildSessionFactory();
}
```

But I need to set also the mapping values:

```
<mapping class="com.web.models.EntranceWFModel"/>
```

How I can set them using Java code?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#addAnnotatedClass-java.lang.Class-

Comment: Related question: [Setting properties programmatically in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074678).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Configuration Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Class annotatedClass)` method](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#addAnnotatedClass-java.lang.Class-), for example:

```
configuration.addAnnotatedClass(EntranceWFModel.class);
```